# With nmap is it possible to scan a private network from outside?

Tags: nmap

Is it possible for a hacker to scan my computer using this command: `nmap 10.0.0.0/8` even if he is not connected to my network ? (and if my private IP is 10.0.2.24 for instance)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

No.  Because the 10.0.0.0/8 block is not routed (or at least should not be routed) on the Internet, and everything behind it is redirected to a real world address for each user, someone on the wider Internet can not simply portscan it.

There are, of-course, exceptions - but these would, in effect, require the hacker become part of your network, for example, joining a VPN (if you have one - you probably don't) which allows that range to be reachable, or if one of your devices is compromised and he can get in and scan via that device, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Hacking as it goes is not that simple like using a commercially or freely available tool to scan private networks

On a very high level, So using these tools, one can scan for open ports, and then they would try to connect using one of those open ports

if you are concern is security that a hacker can just scan your computer using nmap, then this concern is incorrect or the question is not valid